# How to update Calendar events programatically ? I am unable to update

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am unable to update calendar event details programmatically. Here is the code sample. Any help should be greatly appreciated.

```
        Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(CALENDAR_URI, null, null, null, null);
        String[] s = c.getColumnNames();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {

                String _id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                String CalId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("calendar_id"));
                if ((_id == null) && (CalId == null)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if (_id.equals(eventId) && CalId.equals(cal_Id)) {
                        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CALENDAR_URI, Integer.parseInt(_id));
                        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
                        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS, statusId);

                        context.getContentResolver().update(uri, event, null, null);// need to give your data here
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How are you unable? Does it crash, it does nothing, ...?

Comment: @ricardo silva yes it crashes with following message . IllegalArgumentException. Unable to update SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS

Comment: did you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29507471/5166080)?

Comment: It is not working silva

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't help, as I already stated in my first comment. **Why** doesn't it work?

Comment: because I can able to update description,title and status from EVENTS table. But Attendance data is not updating.